# What's the difference between 'hasn't done something for 3 years' and 'hasn't done something in 3 years'?

Tags: difference

What's the difference between 'hasn't done something for 3 years' and 'hasn't done something in 3 years'? For example,

1. He hasn't played the piano for 3 years.
2. He hasn't played the piano in 3 years.

Is there any difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's been [a significant shift](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=not%20been%20there%20in%20years%2Cnot%20been%20there%20for%20years&year_start=1860&year_end=2010&corpus=26&smoothing=10) in (American more than British) *usage*  in recent decades...

[image]

...but the choice of preposition doesn't affect the *meaning.* Obviously this kind of usage shift doesn't reflect some "new" meaning that people never needed to express years ago.

Note that at least *some* people will be (consciously or unconsciously) "attuned" to this language shift, and they may well thus tend to categorise the *earlier* style as more "literary, formal". Not because that categorisation ever *was* true - but if you usually read the older version in older texts, but hear and use the newer version in conversations today, that's how things tend to end up.

Comment: the answer is just american vs british?

Comment: No.It's just that the usage shift started earlier and is more pronounced in the Google Books AmE corpus. [This](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=not+been+there+in+years%2Cnot+been+there+for+years&year_start=1860&year_end=2010&corpus=29&smoothing=10) is the BrE usage chart, showing that the same change is happening in the UK. Because of the Internet, etc., English is becoming more homogeneous across the world, so as a rule even if there *are* US/UK differences, they *tend* to disappear over time.

Comment: Notwithstanding the final paragraph in my answer, it's worth noting that modern technology gives more people more opportunities to write "searchable" text. Which naturally leads to things like Google Books reporting an increase in "informal" usages. But speech (not writing) is the *basis* of language, so the net result is any usage shift I might illustrate with a Google Books chart is in reality probably much more advanced than the charts would suggest.