# For <period of time> vs In <period of time>

Tags: prepositions, time

> 1. I haven't seen him **for** 3 years.
> 2. Most of the fields he'd passed **in** the last few weeks were bare.

Why there is "for" in the first sentence whilst the last one uses "in"?
Is there any difference between the prepositions in the context and can they be swapped without losing the meaning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since he wasn't passing fields the *entire time,* "for" would be incorrect in the second sentence. "Most of the fields he'd passed for the last few weeks were bare" would imply that he was spending all his time passing fields throughout the last few weeks, not just that it was happening occasionally.

In the first sentence, you could use either "in" or "for." "I haven't seen him in 3 years" would also be correct.

Comment: I think of _I haven't seen him in three years_ as being American usage, but according to [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/330848/whats-the-difference-between-hasnt-done-something-for-3-years-and-hasnt-do?rq=1), the change from _for_ to _in_ has been happening on both sides of the Atlantic, just more quickly over there.

Comment: Where I am (Northeast US), "in" is more idiomatic than "for," but either is very much acceptable.